# R SSH tunnel to MySQL database via Shiny App Access Denied or Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: mysql, r, ubuntu, ssh, shiny

I've looked through other posts without success, so here we are. The following code snippet runs as expected on a Windows 10 laptop in RStudio.

```
library(RMySQL)
library(ssh)
library(callr)

rs <- r_session$new(wait = TRUE, wait_timeout = 3500)

rs$call(function(){
  session <- ssh::ssh_connect('<ssh-user>@<remote-ip-address>', keyfile = "<path-to-.pem-file>", verbose = FALSE)
  
  ssh::ssh_tunnel(session, port=3306, target = "127.0.0.1:3306")
})

# Connect to TRAQ DB.
Sys.sleep(1)

db-connection <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = '<remote-user-name>', password = '<remote-password>', dbname = '<remote-database>', port=3306, host='127.0.0.1')
```

The snippet runs runs successfully too when dbConnect() has host='localhost'

---

I am attempting to run the snippet on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 22 within an R shiny app. I receive the following messages while trying to load the app

**Using localhost:**

`ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '<remote-user-name>'@'localhost'`

**Using 127.0.0.1:**

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`

I have received the (115) error code too.

---

If run directly from the R terminal, the snippet must be modified as follows for success.

```
ssh::ssh_tunnel(session, port=3306, target = "127.0.0.1:3306")
```

to

```
ssh::ssh_tunnel(session, port=3307, target = "127.0.0.1:3306")
```

**AND**

```
db-connection <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = '<remote-user-name>', password = '<remote-password>', dbname = '<remote-database>', port=3306, host='127.0.0.1')
```

to

```
db-connection <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = '<remote-user-name>', password = '<remote-password>', dbname = '<remote-database>', port=3307, host='127.0.0.1')
```

If the host is set to 'localhost' or ports are left at 3306, an Access denied message is displayed.

---

Unclear if this is due to a MySQL discrepancy or an operating system discrepancy. I don't believe it to be an issue on the remote server being SSH'd into since it works on the Windows laptop.

Answer (score 0):

select user,host from mysql.user; Check your legal username and host and replace it. In addition, there is a difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost. You should pay attention to whether the /etc/hosts file is mapped.